# Call an observable API each 5 minutes AngularV6+ .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, setinterval

I want to call an `Observable` method (which is calling and external API) every 5 minutes in angular `.ts` file.

For example, I have a method like this:

```
updateMasterTokenAsync(): Observable<boolean> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<any>(
        this.API_URL + this.API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN,
        {'username': 'test', 'password': 'test'},
        {headers: httpHeaders}
    ).pipe(
        tap(res => localStorage.setItem('accessToken', res['token'])),
        map(
            res => true,
            error => false
        )
    );
}
```

I want this method to be called each 5 minutes. I used `setInterval` solution, But it's not working properly. It will call my method but the `http.post` section is not working well. Can anybody help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to subscribe to observables for them to work, and there's no need to use setInterval here since rxjs comes with an invterval and timer observable..

```
timer(0, 300000).pipe(
   switchMapTo(this.updateMasterTokenAsync())
).subscribe(
  result => console.log(result),
  err => console.log(err)
)
```

just unsubscribe from this whenever you're destroying the component or service.

this will start right away, if you want the first call to wait 5 minutes, then use `interval()`